# How do you do <input type="number" /> in Native Base?

Tags: native-base

In HTML, you can use `<input type='number' />` to restrict the user's input to numbers only. It also adds little increment/decrement numbers on the input field. Is there a way to do this in Native Base (v3.2.2)? What is the associated `onChange` property (`onChange`, `onChangeText`, `onValueChange`, etc.)?

I have scoured [the official documentation](https://docs.nativebase.io/input) and have found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find the issue and turned out that `react-native-web` ( one of NativeBase core dependencies) is not passing the props to the HTML Input.

I have created a [PR](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web/pull/2216) for its fix.